# ThreadPoolExecutor Implementation for method taking ArrayList Parameter

Tags: java, jsp

I have a following code

```
private List<String[]> userList2 = new ArrayList<String[]>(10000);

ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

Database Query

```
while (rs.next()) 
{
            data = new String[2];
            data[0] = rs.getString("userid");
            data[1] = rs.getString("email");
            userList2.add(data);

           if(userList2.size()==10000)  //Confusion in this part..
           {

            final List<String[]> elist = new ArrayList<String[]>(userList2);
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                doBilling(con,elist);  //Parallel is not happening here... 

            }
            });
```

I have a method

```
doBillng(Connection con,List<String[]> userList)
{

String list[]=null; 
String userid=" ";
 for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++)
    {
        list=userList.get(i);
        userid=props[0];
        list = BillingDao.billById(uid, con);

    }
}
```

When userlist2 size is 10000 I want to run doBilling in 10 Threads parallelly such that it can reach 10000 records in great speed. But it's not happening!!! Please suggest What am I doing wrong and how should this be solved..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have submitted only one task to the `executor` and that happens when `if(userList2.size()==10000)` returns `true`. So consequently , You have **one** `Thread` running to process 10000 elements of the ArrayList!!!!!.

If you want 10 threads to execute 10000 elements of ArrayList your code should be something like this:

```
while (rs.next()) 
{
    data = new String[2];
    data[0] = rs.getString("userid");
    data[1] = rs.getString("email");
    userList2.add(data);
    if(userList2.size()% 1000 == 0)  //Check if size is multiple of 1000(obtained by 10000/10)
    {
        final List<String[]> elist = new ArrayList<String[]>(userList2);
        executor.execute(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                doBilling(con,elist);  //create new ArrayList and assign it to a seperate thread.
            }
        });
        userList2.clear();//clearing the arrayList so that next time when submitted to executor , new elements are processed.
    }
}
```

Comment: So Do I have to use Loop inside run method??

Comment: @Vishal.. Thanks a lot.. So, by your code  elist is a new ArrayList which is assigned to each separate thread  and by using userList2.size()%1000==0  will be able to parallelly run doBilling method...  which runs 1000 at each thread.. ??   Isn't it?

Comment: yes.it is ...But still there might be chances of your program to hang if tasks keeps enqueued in the queue. But once queue gets full or corepool threads become empty new threads will be allocated to the tasks present in queue one by one.

Comment: If that solved your problem Mark the answer as accepted. by clikcing on the Tick sign below the voting number of my answer. You can know how to accept answer at here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work